# What other reasons did the Separatists have for Separatism?

Tags: star-wars

I am doing a report on the element of [Separatism](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems) in Star Wars, but have only found that the various Unions and Planets wanted to separate because of high taxes on trade routes and corruption in the Senate. Aside from Palpatine's/Darth Sidious's ulterior motives, are there any other reasons that the Separatists wanted to secede from the Republic? (Answers do not have to be canon)

Comment: Oh lordy. A question about the worst part of the films.

Comment: @Richard Nah, those are the going to be the next trilogy coming up.

Comment: "Turmoil has engulfed the Galactic Republic. The taxation of trade routes to outlying star systems is in dispute... [yadda yadda yadda]" (cue picture of young kids trying to understand what the hell the movie is about)

Comment: Free trade areas and lack of govt interference are powerful motivators.

Comment: The Separatists are Libertarians!

Comment: @Richard - I don't see a mention of Jar-Jar in the question

Comment: @SSumner - It was implied.

Comment: @Richard I always thought the "worst part of the films" (aside from anything involving Jar Jar not dying a horrible death at the hands of pretty much anyone) was General Grievous-the first cyborg in the history of everything that had, wait for it, asthma. Despite being capable of walking on the outside of a space craft OUTSIDE a planets atmosphere, he still suffered respiratory distress on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: @geewhiz - I always thought he was a cool character, minus the asthma

Comment: @SSumner - He was fine except for the asthma but the asthma ruined it for me. I was literally sitting in the theater missing a large chunk of the beginning of the movie because I was thinking "he's coughing so he has to breathe but now he's running on the outside of the ship where there isn't any air to breathe and that doesn't seem to bother him one damn...wait what just happened?"

Comment: @SSumner Maybe that's the reason--they didn't want to be a part of a society where Jar Jar could be a respected figure.

Comment: @geewhiz I kinda hated that the whole asthma thing was a "Oh, if you read/watched this thing outside of the movie, then you'd totally get it!" sort of thing. It alienated part of the audience, and lead to a kind of laughable character.

Comment: @Richard - "worst"? You must be one of those pro-Palpatine people!

Comment: @DVK - It's like watching The West Wing... In SPAAACE!

Comment: @Richard - West Wing had Jar-Jar?

Comment: @DVK - Ainsley Hayes.

Comment: High taxes, corruption in the government. Those two reasons were good enough to turn 13 British colonies into the awesomeness that is America. What more do you need? Of course, 250 years later we're back to having high taxes & corruption in the government.

Comment: @Anders F. worst they are neo liberals and are acting in free trade interests (btw they also are agains banks regulations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***In-universe de jure reasons:***

- As you mentioned, corruption in the Senate.

  As one example, Chancellor Valorum's actions were governed by the fact that his family owned a shipping cartel.
- Overall inefficiency in the Senate.

  Note the respone (or rather lack of it) to Naboo crisis. Red tape, bureaucracy, squabbling.
- Another concern is covered in part in the Luceno's "Tarkin" novel (new Disney canon).

  It shows the process of Count Dooku trying to entice Eriadu's governor (Tarkin) to join the Separatists. The concerns (aside from abovementioned corruption and taxation) are basically that the Core worlds syphon power AND resources from the Outer Rim; and treat Outer Rim worlds as second class/subservient entities.

  When Eriadu was plundered by pirates and outlaws, the Core did nothing at all to help, didn't have any Judicials' or Jedi resources. It took Tarkins' aggressiveness to take care of the issue locally.

  This was directly addressed by Count Dooku (to Tarkin) when discussing the upcoming insurrection:

  > “I am committed to the idea of a galaxy ruled by an enlightened leader, **with laws that apply universally—not one set for the Core Worlds, another for the Outer Rim worlds**.”

---

**Out of Universe reasons**

- Lucas, the true child of the counterculture generation, loves merchandizing (Ewoks!) when it lines his own pockets but (unsurprisingly for Hollywood) has shown deep ideological distrust in capitalism.

  Note the major participants in CIS: *Corporate Alliance, Trade Federation, Commerce Guild, InterGalactic Banking Clan and the Techno Union*.

  Basically, moneyed interests cause strife for their own benefit.

  This was put into character's words by Lucas:

  > "I know of your treaties with the Trade Federation, the Commerce Guilds, and the others, Count. What is happening here is not government that has been bought out by business, it's business becoming government!" - *Padmé Amidala to Count Dooku*

---

**In-universe de facto reasons**

- Lest someone thinks I made the out of universe part up, this is fully supported in canon. Several characters - from ALL walks of life (from "A New Dawn"'s conspiracy theorist and anti-The-Man Skelly - to The Man himself, Grand Moff Wilhuff Tarkin) - directly express that the whole Clone Wars in their opinion was manipulated by moneyed powers to enrich and empower themselves.

  Of course, they aren't THAT far off the base, except it was the Sith (Palpatine and Dooku) who manipulated things.